# Why spamassasin is doing dns lookup?

Tags: email, dns, spam, trojan

I have a server which have configured Amavis and Spamassasin (in default state only). I recently noticed log lines that probably indicate DNS query failure, below is an excerpt:

```
Nov 21 11:15:40 spamfilter-1 amavis[4029071]: (4029071-15) p001 1 Content-Type: text/plain, 7bit, size: 189, SHA1 digest: 8903fa98a76ec9fba2c5753b991ffa4f0a55d1a5
Nov 21 11:15:40 spamfilter-1 amavis[4029071]: (4029071-15) SA info: dns: no callback for id 61861/IN/NS/dnsfailover.net, ignored, packet on next debug line
Nov 21 11:15:40 spamfilter-1 amavis[4029071]: (4029071-15) SA info: dns: no likely matching queries for id 61861
```

Apparently, the domain it is trying to resolve is a malicious domain so the firewall blocked it (and that's how it came to notice).

I went through the mail which I think triggered this event but there is no mention of this domain in either body or header. Even when I use spamc on this email it doesn't give me any indicative report. I want to find exactly why spamassasin tried to resolve this domain. (I also ran rkhunter so I guess there is not trojan in linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear from the provided information what exactly happens for your specific case. But it is likely some of SPF, DKIM, DMARC, MX ,.. . This is just what spam filters usually do when they analyze a mail and try to detect spoofing, validity of sender etc. Some filters also check links included in the mail to detect if they server malicious content, but I don't think that Spamassasin does this.

Comment: What additional information do you think I should provide which can help?

Comment: @SUNITAGUPTA: the specific DNS lookups., including the type (MX, TXT)

Comment: Thanks and sorry I figured out based on tcpdump and process accounting that spamassasin was not the actual culprit it's actual another process was sending DNS queries and spam assassin was just polling them so got the 'no callback id' warning.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out based on tcpdump and process accounting that spamassasin was not the actual culprit it's actual another process was sending DNS queries and spam assassin was just polling them so got the 'no callback id' warning.